# Version Control And Pipeline for AWS Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, version-control, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I'm trying to figure out a way to come up with a CI/CD pipeline for CloudFormation. We use Cloudformation Console directly to deploy our infrastructure and app to the cloud.

Does anyone have any examples of how they have created a CI/CD pipeline using Jenkins or other types of CI tools to do some type of linting, CI, version control, and artifact deployment to Artifactory (or similar toolset)? I'd like to execute a pipeline once a new version of the cloud formation templates is uploaded to Artifactory.

Comment: Is it necessary to use external tools, or would CodePipeline work as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use CodePipeline.
see docs:
[CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/getting-started-codepipeline.html)

**CI:**

I am using GitHub, so before i can merge a pull request, my code must pass 3 tests.
Those tests are 3 `Codebuilds` containers that run tests.

**CD:**

After my code merged it invoke a `CodePipeline` that use mainly `CodeDeploy` and `CodeBuild`.

**About your goal:**

> I'd like to execute a pipeline once a new version of the cloud formation templates is uploaded to Artifactory.

I don't really think you need a pipeline for this.
Let assume your artifacts uploaded to s3 bucket called `artifact-bucket`.

You can create a `CloudWatch` rule that will execute `StepFunctions` state machine when file added to
`artifact-bucket`.

see docs:
[Trigger StepFunctions from S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-cloudwatch-events-s3.html)

You can easily deploy stack with StepFunctions.